# Offsetting from a pivot item

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

The goal of the code below is to loop through items in a pivot table, and if an item meets the conditions, print a date in the cell 6 columns over to an area not in the pivot table. Pivot item object does not appear to support offset. Is there another way to offset from the pivot item?

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")

Set pvt = Worksheets("Dashboard").PivotTables("ProcessPivot")
Set Ptfield = pvt.PivotFields("HelperColumn")

For Each pi In Ptfield.PivotItems
    If pi = NameSID And Eventdate2 <> "12:00:00 AM" Then
        pi.Offset(0, 6) = Eventdate2
    ElseIf pi = NameSID Then
        pi.Offset(0, 6) = "Not Reviewed"
    End If
Next pi
End With
```

Comment: offset applies only to a range. pivotitem is not a range. you're not looping the range of your pivottable, just the collection in your pivotfield

Comment: Right, which is why pivotitem does not support the offset property, but is there a way to? Can I somehow get the cell range of the data point and use that to offset?

Answer (score 1):

Something like the following will use the range of the data in the pivot table. Please amend to suit your needs.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim pvt As PivotTable
    Dim rng As Range


    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Dashboard")

    Set pvt = Worksheets("Dashboard").PivotTables("ProcessPivot")

    'Assumes we are checking column 2
    Set rng = Intersect(pvt.DataBodyRange, Worksheets("Dashboard").Columns(2))


    For Each cel In rng
        cel.Offset(, 6) = "enter something"
    Next cel
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, so bear with me. Instead of setting a looping through pivot items in a pivot field, I use the column of reference in the pivot table, set it as a range and loop through that?

Comment: This returns an "Argument not Optional" error at the set rng.

Comment: @MsAgentM That's what I was thinking. Use the pivot table as a range of cells. Also, I didn't get that error in my sample code. Is there any way you can try to figure out what exactly is causing the problem. For example, set the first `pvt.DataBodyRange` to a variable, and set `Worksheets("Dasboard").Columns(2)` to a different variable, and try taking `Intersect(var1, var2)` to see which of the assignments is causing the error.

Comment: Ok, I am pretty new to VBA pivot tables, but I think the issue is, in reading the way the intersect function works, this table IS only one column, so there is no real way to intersect on here. I am trying to find other ways to reference or set this pivot table column as a range. I don't see any direct instruction on this in what I have read so far.

Comment: I have it now! If I remove the intersect function and just to set {rng=pvt.DataBodyRange} the code functions correctly. Thanks for your time!

Comment: @MsAgentM Not a problem. One thing to keep in mind is that the `.DataBodyRange` property will be all of the cells in the pivot table. So, if you have multiple columns, it will loop over all of these cells, and not be limited to only searching one column.